# Field 'id' expected a number but got <QuerySet [<Department: GEE>]>

Tags: python, django

I can't find the mistake here. I saw some similar questions but still can't fix it.

here is my models.py

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    department = models.ManyToManyField(Department, blank=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    department = models.ManyToManyField(Department, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class StudentRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['department', ..]
        widgets = {'department': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StudentRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['department'].required = True

    def clean_department(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data.get('department')
        if len(value) > 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You can't select more than one department!")
        return value

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.save()
        student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
        student.department.add(self.cleaned_data.get('department')) <-- got error on this line
        return (user, student)
```

When the `CustomUser` object is created, the `Student` object will also be created within `save`  method. But for some reasons it gave me an error

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <QuerySet [<Department: GEE>]>.
```

Noticed that the Department objects were created within admin panel and also the department field within the `Student` model works just fine if I create it inside admin panel.

Comment: what are you getting from this "value = self.cleaned_data.get('department')"

Comment: list of department field but i just fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding * into the `add` method like this

```
student.department.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('department'))
```